# Unable to use a when...thenReturn on a mocked object in Mockito Junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am mocking the object of class MockClass and using the when clause to return someClassObject when one of its methods is called ( which is internal to methodToBeTested ). Now in the last line of the code below when I make a call to methodToBeTested , I hope that a internal call to someMethod would run successfully . But there is a nullPointerException which happens in the line of the call to someMethod . Why is my mockObject still null ? I am using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)  as indicated in a lot of threads here .

Edit: As per @Dawood , I replaced @Mock MockClass mockObject with @InjectMocks MockClass mockObject . The output I have below is after this replacement. My idea is that someMethod is not executed in the below line.
when(mockObject.someMethod(arg1,arg2)
But it does get executed and I have an exception being thrown from within it. What am I doing incorrectly here as I want to only mock the method and define what output it gives rather than calling it

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public testClassToBeTested{

    @Mock
    MockClass mockObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        Whitebox.setInternalState(ClassToBeTested, "argumentName",
            arg2);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodToBeTested{

        Class1 arg1 = new Class1();
        Class1.setUserId("test");

        //someMethod which is called within methodToBeTested
        when(mockObject.someMethod(arg1,arg2).thenReturn(someClassObject));

        ClassAnotherClass anotherClassObject = ClassToBeTested.methodToBeTested(arg1);

    }

}
```

Console output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.utils.MockClass.someMethod(MockClass.java:36)
at com.mycompany.impl.ClassToBeTested.methodToBeTested(ClassToBeTested.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Just because your test creates a mock instance of MockClass (i.e. mockObject) doesn't mean ClassToBeTested.methodToBeTested() uses it. You need to make sure it indeed uses that mock instance. Typically by passing this mock instance to the constructor of ClassToBeTested, and make sure methodToBeTested does use the value that was passed in the constructor. I.e. use dependency injection.

Comment: Yes I do have a @Inject MockClass mockObject located inside of ClassToBeTested which does the Dependency injection

Comment: No, it won't. Not when calling a static method like you're doing. And not in a unit test where there is no DI framework involved.

Comment: Downvoting because the question has no complete code sample (including the line throwing exception) nor the Stacktrace, nor mentioning which injection method is used.

Comment: Mockito doesn't scan all your classes for `@Inject` annotations - that's not its job.  You need to either inject your mocks explicitly, or use the Mockito `@InjectMocks` annotation in your test class.

Comment: Downvoted for the very same reasons ... and on top of that, OP not being responsive. http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: Guys , this is a lot of pressure . Please give me sometime and I will post the output, sorry for not being more detailed . I did use @InjectMocks as mentioned by Dawood above . Now I get an error at when(mockObject.someMethod(arg1,arg2). I thought mocking doesn't call the method but in this case someMethod is actually getting executed

Comment: Don't put more information into comments please. "Simply" make sure that you have a **true** [mcve] inside your question. Then drop a comment to the people who asked you to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to tell since your code example is not complete, not a direct copy, and you also did not paste the NPE or the line in which it happens. Chances are:

#### The mock is not injected

In that case you could put @Inject on the constructor of the class and manually inject the mock in the test, just to make sure.

#### The mock returns null

This can happen if the mock arguments do not match, or some other error in the mocking code.

In the example you do not mock correctly:

```
when(mockObject.someMethod(arg1,arg2).thenReturn(someClassObject));
```

should be

```
when(mockObject.someMethod(arg1,arg2)).thenReturn(someClassObject);
```

Notice the change in parentheses

Comment: I suspect OP has actually used parentheses correctly in their code, but has failed to copy-paste their code correctly.  Otherwise, their code wouldn't compile.  But absolutely, it looks like their problem is that the mock isn't injected.